# Why does this pattern matching does not work?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have a generic class `Book[T](index: Int, type: T)`, and an object `foo` of type `Book`. I'm not sure how to access the index and the type. I've tried:

```
1. foo match { case Book[T](index: Int, type:T) => {} }
2. foo match { case Book(index: Int, type:T) => {} }
3. foo match { case foo: Book[T] => { foo.index } }
```

All fail with messages:

```
1. class Book does not take type parameters
2. class Book not found
3. index is not a member of Book
```

Thank you.

Comment: So you have `case class Book[T](index: Int, \`type\`: T)` as book definition?

Comment: @om-nom-nom - That is a rhetorical question, right?  It's clearly _not_ a `case class` or `index` would be a member of `Book`.  So that's one problem....

Comment: @RexKerr ... well, let's show all cards: `type` is a keyword in scala, so one does not simply use it as variable name: @user1377000 have to escape it with backticks.

Comment: it's just `class Book[T](index: Int, type: T)`.

Comment: OK just... how could I achieve what I want?

Comment: @user1377000 - No it's not.  That doesn't compile. `scala> class Book[T](index: Int, type: T)
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but 'type' found.
       class Book[T](index: Int, type: T)`.  Anyway, it's not clear what you want.  Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish with `type: T`, and whether the caller is going to know what `T` is or not (i.e. is it still generic)?

Answer (score 1):

Well `type` is a keyword already used by scala.
you can try achieving same by using someother keyword instead of `type` and using `case class` to pattern match.

```
 case class Book[T](index: Int, bookType : T)

  val foo =  Book(1,Book)                         

  // foo  : stack.Book[stack.Book.type] = Book(1,Book)

  foo match {
    case Book(i,t) => "index : " + i + ", type : " + t // play around with i & t
  }                                     

 //> res0: String = index : 1, type : Book
```

Comment: What's the difference between `class Book` and `case class Book`?

Comment: also, if you don't want to use case class, consider http://www.scala-lang.org/node/112